# Embed setting was invalid (invalidEmbedSetting)

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

When creating a broadcast using Youtube api, the youtube api return error.
But in youtube studio was able to check `embbed video`

[image]

The problem is when set attribute `setEnableEmbed` to **true**

```
LiveBroadcastContentDetails contentDetails = liveBroadcast.getContentDetails();
contentDetails.setEnableDvr(updateLiveDTO.isCreateVideoOnDemand());
contentDetails.setEnableEmbed(Boolean.TRUE);
```

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveBroadcasts?part=snippet,contentDetails,status
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "youtube.liveBroadcast",
    "message" : "Embed setting was invalid",
    "reason" : "invalidEmbedSetting",
    "extendedHelp" : "https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts#contentDetails.enableEmbed"
  } ],
  "message" : "Embed setting was invalid"
}
```

Comment: This seems to be an [issue that it quite recurrent](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/158696654) with Google's own issue tracker. Google staff themselves weren't able to provide an answer to this issue.